# Line Separator ‘\u2028’ parse incorrect using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var newLineChar = Char.Parse("\u2028");
    var jsonStr = @"{""value"":""some chars " + newLineChar + @"""}";

    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

    var jsonStrAfterParse = jObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
}
```

I have a JSON string like:

> "{\"value\":\"some chars \u2028\"}"

After I try to parse it using Newtonsoft.Json, I got the JSON:

> "{\"value\":\"some chars \\u2028\"}"

The Line Separator char '\u2028' was parsed to '\\u2028'. I cannot make sure whether any other chars have the same issue. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

[Pic in immediate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPMb.png)

[jsonStr in text visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7LaC.png)

[jsonStrAfterParse in text visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Djhh.png)

Comment: Please share the value of `jsonStr` from the Immediate Window. Also the same for  `jsonStrAfterParse`.

Comment: @mjwills I added several pics

Comment: I _can_ reproduce this behavior with both `\u2028` and `Environment.NewLine`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41607707/4934172) seems to be related.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this question now. Are you saying that you expect \u2028 to still appear as a character, unencoded, in the JSON string? Or what? It's working [as I expect it to](http://rextester.com/CJQRG25286).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the expected behavior. @erYYer Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908960/4934172) as well.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you established that it's expected behavior, but I thought I'd go into *why* based on the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs).

Your input string is not valid JSON because of the unescaped control character `\u2028`, but NewtonSoft.Json is gracefully handling the bad input, and giving correct output of `\\u2028` when you ask it to serialize for you.

For the deserialization, it doesn't care that you didn't escape it. It just goes ahead and includes it with your string. No biggie.

But when you ask it to serialize the string for you with `.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)`--which is a Newtonsoft extension method--its job is to give you valid JSON, and by golly, that's what it's going to do, giving you the `\\u2028` you see.